# Can socket.getaddrinfo port number be given as a string?

Tags: python

These are normal getaddrinfo uses:

```
socket.getaddrinfo('localhost',25)
socket.getaddrinfo('localhost','smtp')
```

but this works as well (tried in Python 3.4):

```
socket.getaddrinfo('localhost','25')
```

Seems logical to me, but the documentation says:

> port is a string service name such as 'http', a numeric port number or
>   None

Can a string like '25' be considered *numeric*? Is the last getaddrinfo example OK?

Comment: Probably the function converts the string as a last resort if it cannot find a service named `'25'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python socket module is a wrapper around the C API for the BSD socket interface. In this interface, the `getaddrinfo` function takes a `service` parameter which is a string that can be either a service name, a string representation of a port number, or null.

[As seen here](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Modules/socketmodule.c#L4005), the Python function converts the corresponding argument to a string (if needed) and calls the C `getaddrinfo` function. So it will work equivalently with both `25` and `'25'`.

Comment: Good idea to check the underlying C function. It is `int getaddrinfo(const char *node, const char *service, ...)`. Answer accepted.